# Using Ajax to fetch data without reloading the page

Tags: jquery

I have been pulling my hair out with Ajax and how to fetch data from the MYSQL database and displaying without the page reloading. I have read so many articles, forum topics etc and every single one talks about displaying tables. All I want to display is ***one*** value! I need the money value to be updated when something is completed for it to go up or down.

This is my code:

***api.php***

```
    <?php 
session_start();
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'secure.php';
include 'smile.php';
include 'checks.php'; 
logincheck();     

$username=$_SESSION['username'];


  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");          //query
  $info = mysql_fetch_object($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($info);

?>
```

***game.php***

```
 <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function ()           
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      data: 'json',                //data format      
      context:document.body,success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id=(<?php echo $info->money ;?>);              //get id
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 3) Update html content
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        $('#output').html("$"+id); //Set output element html
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 
        // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
      } 
    });
  }); 

  </script>
```

The value does display but it doesn't update insantly, I'm tearing my hair out with this damn thing. If anyone can help me that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You should really be using PDO or SQLi to protect against SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use PHP in your success function, that is what your data parameter is for.

This line:

```
var id=(<?php echo $info->money ;?>);
```

Should be something like this:

```
var id=(data[money]); //Check your data variable to see exact organization.
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: That's what I get when I change it to that buddy. Any more help?

Comment: Any more help guys would be great.

Comment: @Trippy what is `$info` right before your php file ends? Is it what you expect? Also, as I said in my answer, you **cannot** use php in your success function is that still what you are doing? An Internal Server Error generally means something is wrong in your php